# Git automatically pull, commit and push?

Tags: web-server, home-automation

I'm looking to implement Git on my Raspberry Pi and wanted to know if there is any software out there to automatically sync both ways so it's always an up-to-date copy?

The stages would be:

1. The system reads a list of remote repository URLs to sync
2. The system then iterates these and passes each one to Git
3. Git will then pull down the latest revision of each repository
4. The system will monitor file changes and re-commit/push these to the repository

Comment: Hi Dean.  You'll get better help with this on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) or [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) (this place is for questions that are actually about the pi specifically). To clarify first, if I understand you correctly you want something so that when you go to (e.g.) pull on machine A from a common repo on server S, server S will check to see if a parallel repo on machine B (presuming that is online) has a commit to push first?

Comment: Hi @goldilocks i've updated the post to be clearer

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like: https://git-annex.branchable.com/sync/

That being said, this question would better fit on [Super User](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#Super_User).

Answer (score 0):

`cron` job and some scripting. It is simple enough to use as what you need is only `cron` and `git` which it is pretty much 100% there where you need it.

Comment: Until you have a three way merge problem...