# How can I automatically deploy my code changes to my Raspberry Pi?

Tags: pi-3, python, software-development

What is a good Continuous Integration / Continuous Deployment solution with Raspberry Pi?

**EDIT**

The developer experience with writing programs directly on the PI is suboptimal and potentially lossy, in that the only place the source code exist is on the target device.

When developing applications for large enterprises, I usually work with a team of developers on the same project who synchronize and merge their code changes in Git or some other source control system. We are able to collaborate, consolidate changes, even roll back changes if a recent change was not wanted.

In my current project, our work flow includes developer code review, merging code changes, and then promotion of the consolidated code to the master branch. When changes have been promoted to master, an automated process will build and package the application and then deploy it to the server.

Professionally a release pipeline like this readily attainable for Web sites and other types of applications on many platforms, but I haven't found a standard approach for deploying code to devices yet.

When developing code to control components on a Raspberry Pi, my preference is to develop code on my laptop, push it to a Git repository, and have that automatically deployed to the Pi after a merge to the master branch.

The closest that I've seen to an answer is from this question, which has been deemed off topic: [Git automatically pull, commit and push?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14538/git-automatically-pull-commit-and-push) I apologize if my question is considered off-topic. I don't see this as off topic, because I write code to interact with the Pi and connected components.

Comment: *"I haven't found a standard approach for deploying code to devices yet"* -> Forgive my sarcasm, but what do you think "web sites and other applications on many platforms" run on?  Point being the Pi is a normal computer in this sense; the only issue here would be that the availability of proprietary software will be limited by the ARM architecture.

Comment: I would ask this at https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/products/developer-tools/ some of these tools could help you, but imho your question is too broad

Comment: Another better place to investigate this would be [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).  I also agree with Fabian that you might want to make an effort with a search engine first.  I suspect that the reason you have not had any luck so far is because you've been searching "raspberry pi" instead of "linux".  It's the OS, not the brand of hardware, that is most significant here.  If you find something specific and you are not sure about it, feel free to ask about that.

Comment: Quick and dirty fix would be Dropbox or a Cron job with wget {path to your file}.

Comment: I have searched Bing and Google. Usually stackoverflow would be a good bet, but my first hit brought me here.

Comment: @goldilocks This problem is often solved with tools like VSTS, TFS, Jenkins, or just plain shell scripting. The interesting component would be having a service poll Git for changes or have VSTS push the code and/or binaries to the Pi.

Comment: You've missed the point.  *"but my first hit brought me here"* -> That could only be the case if you are searching "foo **raspberry pi**".  I am telling you not to do that.  This is a common mistake of new Pi users who are also new to linux.  Raspbian is just a slight tweak on Debian, an OS distribution that's been around for more than two decades, is used on a sizable percentage of the world's inet servers,  on every conceivable scale from the tiny to the colossal etc.  Almost all of the software available to those systems is available in Raspbian...

Comment: ...So search "foo **linux**", or if you like, "foo **debian**".  You will have access to orders of magnitude more information.  Again, if you find something specific and aren't sure how feasible it is on the Pi, feel free to ask a more specific question.   Re, use of VCS software or simple scripting ideas, that's a topic for our big sibling [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks. I apologize, if my question is not clear enough, but my searches included terms like DevOps, Raspberry Pi, Automated Deployment, Git, and Python. This is really a developer or DevOps problem that has not been addressed sufficiently for IoT, as far as I can tell. I will take your advice though. I'm a member of all the StackExchange sites that have been mentioned above.

Comment: I made changes which I hope explain the developer experience better, and I what I am hoping to accomplish.

Comment: It strikes me as a perfectly reasonable question for this forum; certainly it is as much "on topic" and "in scope" as many of the other posts we see.

Comment: @AndyAnderson Thanks for the suggestion. It works. I still want a more industrial solution, but your comment is the closest thing I've gotten to an answer on three sites.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/importing-a-git-repository-using-the-command-line/